# How to expand variable whose value contains space properly in scp command?

Tags: bash, variables, scp, expand

When a file name contains spaces ,the file name need escape two times in scp command.
I can get file "somesoft someversion.apk" from remote ip address into my local "tmp" directory:

```
scp user@ip_address:/share/"somesoft\\ someversion.apk"  /tmp
```

It works fine.Now i want to use a var name to refer to the file "somesoft someversion.apk".

```
fname="somesoft someversion.apk"
scp user@ip_address:/share/"$fname"  /tmp
```

The var can't be parsed properly in scp command:

```
scp: /share/somesoft: No such file or directory
scp: someversion.apk: No such file or directory
```

How to expand variable whose value contains space properly in scp command?
Now here is the real case,scp works fine with two time escapes:

[image]

Now to set a var and assign value with it,then scp:
[image]

`"'$fname'"` have no magic effect in this case.

Comment: You have replaced `"\\ "` by `" "`.

Comment: Consider using rsync. Note https://lwn.net/Articles/835962/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to shell quote it.

```
fname="somesoft someversion.apk"
scp user@ip_address:/share/"$(printf "%q" "$fname")"  /tmp
```